# Tricky WHERE condition clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I got into a dilema that seems to be easy but i just can't put it in TSQL.

Let's say I have this Table

```
Service     Master
LOCAL       BRGIL
EREPO       CROMST
NICLI       CROMST
EXPORT      NIGIL
```

I need to disregard all records that in Master they have the value 'CROMST' unless the value in 'Service' is EREPO

so far i've tried

```
WHERE (Master <> 'CROMST' AND ([Service] <> 'EREPO'))
```

This only shows

```
Service     Master
LOCAL       BRGIL
EXPORT      NIGIL
```

i have tried this also

```
WHERE (Master <> 'CROMST' AND (rtrim([Service])+rtrim(Master) <> 'EREPOCROMST'))
```

and still no luck.

I know this should be easy but i am blocked

the result i am looking is

```
Service     Master
LOCAL       BRGIL
EREPO       CROMST
EXPORT      NIGIL
```

Comment: `where master <> 'CROMST' or Service = 'EREPO'`

Comment: `WHERE NOT((Master = 'CROMST' AND ([Service] <> 'EREPO'))`

Comment: Thanks Mihai, that did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM 
your_table
WHERE (Key2 != 'CROMST' OR Key1 = 'EREPO' )
```

would be my approach

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```sql
where master <> 'CROMST' or Service = 'EREPO'
```

**Evaluating the possible scenarios:**

- Scenario: master = 'CROMST'; Service = 'EREPO'

  - *false* or **true**
  - **true**
- Scenario: master != 'CROMST'; Service = 'EREPO'

  - **true** or **true**
  - **true**
- Scenario: master = 'CROMST'; Service != 'EREPO'

  - *false* or *false*
  - *false*
- Scenario: master != 'CROMST'; Service != 'EREPO'

  - **true** or *false*
  - **true**

Comment: awesome and yet simple.

Answer (score 1):

Using case function:

```
DECLARE @myTable AS TABLE
    (
        [SERVICE] VARCHAR(8) ,
        [Master] VARCHAR(8)
    );


INSERT INTO @myTable (   [SERVICE] ,
                         [Master]
                     )
VALUES ( 'LOCAL', 'BRGIL' ) ,
    ( 'EREPO', 'CROMST' ) ,
    ( 'NICLI', 'CROMST' ) ,
    ( 'EXPORT', 'NIGIL' );

    SELECT * FROM @myTable;

    SELECT *
    FROM @myTable
    WHERE 1 =   CASE WHEN ([MASTER] = 'CROMST') 
                    THEN
                        CASE WHEN ([SERVICE] = 'EREPO') 
                            THEN 1 -- special exception
                            ELSE 0 --disregard all others
                        END
                    ELSE 1 -- keep
                END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
WHERE Master <> 'CROMST'
  OR (([Service] = 'EREPO') AND (Master = 'CROMST'))
```

Comment: FYI `AND (Master = 'CROMST')` is superfluous to the logic (though may be helpful in explaining intent).  i.e. as where `master <> 'CROMST'` we want the result regardless of the service value; and where `service = 'EREPO'` we want the result regardless of the master (since if it's CROMST we want it because of the service value; if it's not we want it because of the previous condition).

Answer (score 0):

select *
from your_table a
where not exists (select * from your_table b where b.Master = 'CROMST'
and b.Service <> 'EREPO')

The subquery queries all rows where Master has the value 'CROMST' but the 'Service' value is not 'EREPO'.

The "not exists" filters out the subquery result.